# "Synchrounous" AJAX call and web2py

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web2py

I need some help with "synchronizing" my AJAX calls. I have a function scripted that takes in a file with certain test parameters and uses those parameters to kick off test via an AJAX call/s. The way the code is suppose to work is thatonce the test run is complete, another AJAX call is suppose to update the eventLog with the test results for that run and then move to the next iteration of the for loop.

The ajax calls can be seen in the for loop towards the bottom of the code. I looked into some documentation on using the jQuery Deffered class, but I am pretty new to JavaScript in general and I'm having trouble understanding how that code works. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
function runTest(modelName, serialNum, passArea) {
    //Pull in sequence file
    var str = "";
    var table = document.getElementById('taskTable');
    var output = document.getElementById('outputStrArea');
    var passFail = document.getElementById(passArea).innerHTML;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        str+= row.innerHTML+"\n";
    }
    str = str.split("<td>");
    delete str[0];
    delete str[-1];
    //Create a list of tests that can be read out
    var testList = [];
    for (var i=1; i <str.length; i++){
        str[i]= str[i].replace("</td>", "");
        str[i]= str[i].replace(" ", "");
        if (str[i].search("checkbox") < 0){
            testList.push(str[i]);
        }
    }
    var model = document.getElementById(modelName).innerHTML;
    model = model.replace("<b>", "");
    model = model.replace("</b>", "");
    model = model.replace(" ", "");
    var serial = document.getElementById(serialNum).innerHTML;
    var info = model+" "+serial+" ";
    for(var k=0; k<testList.length; k+=5){
        info+= testList[k]+" "+testList[k+1]+" "+testList[k+2]+" "+testList[k+3]+" "+testList[k+4]+" ";
        ajax("loadTestSequence?info="+info, [], passArea);
        ajax("loadEventLog", [], 'eventLog');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax calls have a success callback in which you can invoke another ajax call id you want. Syntax is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
},
  dataType: dataType
});
```

So now you can chain your respective ajax calls similarly. Hope that helps.

Comment: For the ajax call that web2py provides, it doesn't look like that option is readily available. There is a settings file that allows you to turn async off but I need other portions of the overall code to be asynchronous so I can't fully turn it off.

Comment: Hi Try this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/KZ8NL/2/ I think this will then solve your problem. Hope it is helpful now